# Perl -> PHP

Tags: php, perl

Помогите, пожалуйста, конвертировать PERL на PHP:
1)

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use 5.014;
use CGI qw(:all);
print "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n\n";

open FILE, "text.txt" or die "Cen't open file: $!";
my @fl = <FILE>;
close FILE;

if (@fl[0] >= 10) {
  say "Hello!!!!!";
  exit;
}

unless (param('i') == 1) {
  say @fl[0];
} else {
  open FL, ">text.txt" or die "Cen't open file: $!";
  print FL @fl[0]+1;
  close FL;
  say @fl[0]+1;
}
```

2)

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
print "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n\n";
open FILE, ">text.txt" or die "Cen't open file: $!";
close FILE;
print "Wozzup!";
```

Answer (score 4):

Я бы для начала, привел ваш код к нормальному перлу
perltidy уже дает

```
#1)===============
!/usr/ bin / perl -w

use strict;
use 5.014;
use CGI qw(:all);
print "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n\n";

open FILE, "text.txt" or die "Cen't open file: $!";
my @fl = <FILE>;
close FILE;

if ( @fl[0] >= 10 ) {
    say "Hello!!!!!";
    exit;
}

if ( param('i') != 1 ) {
    say @fl[0];
}
else {
    open FL, ">text.txt" or die "Cen't open file: $!";
    print FL @fl[0] + 1;
    close FL;
    say @fl[0] + 1;
}

#===========
```

а можно отредактировать покрасивше

```
#!/usr/ bin / perl -w
use 5.014;
use CGI qw(:all);
use File::Slurp qw/read_file/;
print "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n\n";

my @fl         = read_file('text.txt');
my $first_line = @fl[0];

if ( $first_line >= 10 ) {
    say "Hello!!!!!";
    exit;
}

if ( param('i') == 1 ) {
    my $next_value = $first_line + 1;
    write_file( 'filename', $next_value );
    say $next_value;
}
else {
    say $first_line;
}

#===========
```

Так же гораздо понятнее, что он делает.
Ну и далее хоть в php хоть в яву.

Дальше, думаю, сам сможешь: [Perl/Php Translation](http://www.cs.wcupa.edu/~rkline/perl2php/).

окончательный вариант вашего счетчика я бы сделал таким

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use 5.014;
use CGI qw(:all);
use File::Slurp qw/read_file write_file/;

#use Carp;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

print "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n\n";

my ($param) = $ARGV[0] || param('i');

#check if input parameters is correct
carp("ERROR: \$param=*$param* is not defined or not number")
  if !defined $param || $param !~ /^\d+$/xms;

my $file_name  = 'text.txt';
my @fl         = read_file($file_name);
my $first_line = $fl[0];

say make_work( $param || 1, $file_name, $first_line );

#say make_work( param('i') || 1, $file_name, $first_line );
#say make_work( 1, $file_name, $first_line );

sub make_work {
    my ( $param, $file_name, $first_line ) = @_;
    given ($param) {
        when ('1') {
            write_file( $file_name, ++$first_line );
            continue;
        }
        when ( $_ >= 10 ) { return 'Hello!!!!!' }
        default           { return $first_line }
    }
}
```